# Dencrypt sensitive strings

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, smarttarget

I am able to encrypt the sensitive strings in Tridion using

> java -cp cd_core.jar com.tridion.crypto.Encrypt mysensitivestring

Is there any way to decrypt it?

Comment: You just "asking for a friend", right? :)

Comment: I like your comment Peter :).

Comment: I encrypted password for broker database and used this in storage_conf.xml ,Now i don't remember my original password. As i want to access broker db so i need to decrypt the password.

Answer (score 3):

Well... if the passwords can be encrypted, they can be decrypted as well. This does requires understanding the system you are working with.

Have a look at my blog post here :http://tridionbasicscity.com/2015/11/09/tridion-tips-decrypting-broker-database-smart-target-passwords-n-gaining-access/

Download the DECRYPTION java class file and use below command to decrypt the passwords. Detailed instructions are on blog post.

[image]

I have shared some Tridion Tips & Tricks including a way to decrypt the passwords not only for Broker databases but for Smart Target as well.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to decrypt it? Tridion content delivery would decrypt the encrypted value to its original string.

Just make sure that you place the following in your configuration file:

*Value="encrypted:YOURENCRYPTEDOUTPUT"*

**Update:**

Can you try the steps suggested in the following [blog](http://kahwah.me/2014/6/decrypting-encrypting-tridion-contentmanager-config)? It would work for Tridion.ContentManager.Config. If it does not, I would recommend contacting SDL Tridion Support

```
mkdir c:\temp

copy YOURCONFIGFILE c:\temp\web.config

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "SECTIONTODECRYPT" c:\temp
```

Comment: @user1717, I hope you have forgot any credential after encrypting it in configuration file. If my guess is correct it may be a database connection string, because usually we encrypt connection string. You can check with SDL support if we can decrypt the encrypted data.